# Where are iptables rules fetched from while running command 'service iptables save'?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I have created my own file- /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config. 
On **service iptables save** my rules are successfully updated and that updates the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file as well.

Now even after i delete the /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config file, and make changes to /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, it will always return to the original one on service iptables save command.

Can you please explain from which file are these rules loaded, on running iptables save command.

Also, if I delete my INPUT chain rules, those are not getting updated on iptables save or restart. How do I update the iptables rules to take the value from iptables file or iptables-config file.